# Python2.7からSocks5でTorを利用してTorサイトにアクセスする方法

Tags: python

通常サイトの場合はこのコードで接続できるんですが、.onionにアクセスしようとすると失敗します。

環境：

```
windows 10
python 2.7
```

コード：

```
import socks
import socket
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

import urllib2
print urllib2.urlopen('http://[url].onion').read()
```

エラー：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    print urllib2.urlopen('http://[url].onion').read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

どうすれば接続できるようになると思いますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.onion` は Tor 上の特殊ドメインなので、DNS リクエストが ToR 越しではなく、通常使用の DNS サーバーに行ったがためにエラーになっているように見受けられます。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184205/dns-over-proxy にあるように、`getaddrinfo` にも Socks5 を使うようにすれば解決すると思います。

Comment: 接続できました！ありがとうございます！